# What data will be lost if I update my phone (WT19i)?

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out

I have this WT19i (currently on ICS). I use a phone lock (it was pattern lock). My friend tried 20 times and it made the phone go to only accepting answers to my security questions. Unfortunately I am unable to remember the answers.

I browsed and found out that I have to update the phone to be able to unlock it. I don't think I ever did backup my data. It said my personal data will be lost after the update. What kind of data is that will be lost?

Comment: Most likely all of your data on your phone. Could you possibly go in to your google account, change your security question answers and then unlock your device?

Comment: "Update"? Do you mean "reset"?

Comment: Before acting too early: I just added the 'locked-out' tag to your question. Please check [its tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first-aid, you might still be able to get away without a reset.